# Clear all string members from object in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, member

I have a class that contains about 500 String members and I'd like to "reset" them all by setting them to String.Empty. Can anybody tell me how to do this using reflection so I can iterate over every String member ?

Thanks

Comment: Something is horribly wrong if you have a class with 500 members

Comment: @Hogan - usually but not necessarily.  @xain - if you read the reflection docs this is pretty obvious, is there a particular problem you're having? (+1 to counteract people assuming that this is stupid)

Comment: @Kieren - what are the odds that someone who can't read the reflection docs is doing this "for the right reason"?  (I personally can't think of a good reason a class would need 500 string members and would love to hear of a use case if you can think of one.)

Comment: @Kieren: Storing 500 strings in an object is not necessarily wrong.  Using individual fields is horribly wrong, an array or dictionary would be much better.

Comment: Bala's answer is good if you are using properties.  Patrick's is good if these are just plain members

Comment: @Ben - again, depending on context.  Maybe it's generated code for some reason, for example.  It is correct to point out that this is unlikely to be the best solution.  However the question is perfectly valid, well-formed and has an exact and deducible answer.

Comment: Actually it'a WPF app that has 10 tabItems which contain in total 500 fields, and I'm using Bindings to map the controls with the 'huge' class.

Comment: What does it matter? It's his problem. He just wants to know how to change the strings, not get a lecture about how bad it might be.

Comment: @Kieren: If it was generated code, you could generate the "reset" method.  And you still would probably want to generate array or dictionary access instead of so many fields.

Comment: @Kieren, if its generated code then it makes sense to generate the "reset" method as well so he doesn't have to suffer the perf penalty of all these reflection calls.

Comment: @Dustin, we've given him a fish in the answers below.... and teaching him to fish in the comments.  All is well

Comment: @Robert Levy heh, good response :)

Comment: @xain - that being the case, you could use an indexer property.  `public string this[string fieldName] { get { ... } }` or a custom TypeDescriptor.  Or a binding using a converter with the field name as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kieren, being a java guy this is all new for me. Could you share some link to study this approach? I'd really like to go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in MyObj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic ).ToArray() )
            {
                if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    pi.SetValue(MyObj, string.Empty, null);
                }
            }
```

For fields use

```
foreach (FieldInfo fi in MyObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic ).ToArray() )
            {
                if (fi.FieldType == typeof(string))
                {
                    fi.SetValue(MyObj, string.Empty);
                }
            }
```

Comment: need to verify that the datatype is string first

Answer (score 6):

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
               .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(p => p.SetValue(myObj,string.Empty, null));
```

EDIT:

If you are dealing with fields and not properties, it's very similar

```
typeof(MyClass).GetFields()
               .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(string))
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(f => f.SetValue(myObj,string.Empty));
```

Comment: @Robert I just edited my answer to include Fields with should cover normal 'members'

Comment: @Sven with IEnumerable, you project and filter stuff but you cannot execute a statement like SetValue() for members of the collection. You'll have to manually loop thru IEnumerable or call ToList() and use the ForEach() extension.

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't have a ForEach so you have to go to IList first... or write a normal foreach loop

Comment: @Robert: right, my memory was playing tricks on me. @Bala: there's no reason why you couldn't, if the method did exist. I could easily write a ForEach extension method myself that does allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Same code implemented using compiled Expression-Tree:

```
private static Action<TObject> CreateClearStringProperties<TObject>()
{
    var memberAccessExpressions = new List<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>();

    System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression arg = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject), "x");

    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(TObject).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) && propertyInfo.SetMethod != null)
        {
            var memberAccess = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arg, propertyInfo);

            var assignment = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(memberAccess, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(string.Empty));

            memberAccessExpressions.Add(assignment);
        }
    }

    foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(TObject).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string))
        {
            var memberAccess = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arg, fieldInfo);

            var assignment = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(memberAccess, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(string.Empty));

            memberAccessExpressions.Add(assignment);
        }
    }

    if (memberAccessExpressions.Count == 0)
        return new Action<TObject>((e) => { });

    var allProperties = System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(memberAccessExpressions, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Block);

    return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Action<TObject>>(allProperties, arg).Compile();
}
```

Example of how to use it:

```
Action<MyClass> clearObject = CreateClearStringProperties<MyClass>();
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
clearObject(obj);
```

Needed it for some generic pooling logic, where objects put back into the pool should not keep obsolete string-objects alive.